# Shared memory programming slower w/newer compilers vs older compilers

Tags: c++, windows, unix, shared-memory

I have a series of c++ batch programs that run concurrently and use shared memory to pass data between them.  The programs are built for windows and UNIX with appropriate code for each using semaphores, mutex, etc.

The shared memory code/libs were written many years ago by a consultant and have worked flawlessly for many years.

This year we upgraded compilers/operating systems to VS2010 for windows and AIX 7. Previously we had to work off 10+ year old compilers.

Everything still works, but we are having significant performance problems. In logging, I have narrowed down to where delays are occurring.

For Windows it is when we do WaitForSingleObject(m_HANDLE, INFINITE);
For UNIX it is when we do semop(m_HANDLE,&sb,1);

I am reading up on this type of primitive coding and it is slow going.

My question is does anyone know of anything in terms of modern operating systems and/or compilers that would cause this type of programming to run slower than older operating systems/compilers?

Comment: There is no **good** reason why these should be any slower. If anything, they should be the same speed, as there's not much compiler involvement at all. If they are slower, there is the possibility that the 10 year old compiler was optimizing in an invalid way, skipping a call to a synchronization function when it shouldn't have. I'm also disinclined to bite for "operating systems are slower" because in my experience, while software gets slower and more bloated every day, operating system kernels actually improved _a lot_ over the last decade.

Comment: The only thing that changed, at all, was the compiler?

Comment: the other change of course are the operating system libraries that get linked in - like the standard c lib.

Comment: Oh, well reminded. But thats still weird because it shouldn't directly affect behaviour of system API calls like `WaitForSingleObject()`, afaik its a DLL call and remains the same regardless of the libc version.

Comment: Everything was a technology upgrade, databases, MSSQL and Sybase, UNIX os, Windows7 w/VS2010, etc.  The c++ now uses std libs.  At first I thought the drag was database related as historically, that is where performance issues came from. But this time, suprisingly, I found the delays to be in the shared memory code which has always been solid for over 15 years. I have rarely had to do maintenance to it and is one of the reasons I am floundering. I am a applications programmer and rarely deal with OS specific things.

Comment: Exactly how much delay are we talking about? A fraction of second per sync operation or a more considerable time?

Comment: It is not consistent delays. One time, the log will show 0 or 1 second, another time will be 3-10 seconds.  It is almost like intermittent cpu spikes from somewhere else.

Comment: Sinse you seem to have changed your whole structure at once, it will be quite a challenge to find out whats wrong. Perhaps its just your database that need some tunning, but if you are sure its the compiler than try to run one of your old builds in your new environment and see how it behaves. If it works like a charm perhaps the Rafael Baptista answer is correct.

Comment: If you also upgraded the hardware from 10 year old machines then one big difference is multiple CPUs/cores. Multithreaded code that was never tested on multiple cores is fairly likely to have sync problems on new hardware.

Comment: From reading since last post, the issue of shared memory programs and multiple CPUs/codes seems to be a common scalability issue.  Any recommendations on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here but...

Probably in the old compiler you were using non-threaded standard c library, and your code was  manually thread locking for many operating system calls.

In the new code, the standard libraries are now threaded by default. It may be what with the new standard libraries you are now locking things more than necessary. I'm not sure MSVC even ships non-thread safe std c libs any more.

Comment: This could be true. While I am not totally sure, I am pretty sure when the original code was written, c++ was still young and the code is probably written to control everything being the it was/is so critical to keep things in sync (large system where the first program reads database, passes data to a proccess program, passes results to 3rd program where results are formatted and written to database)